# Probability of getting out of a circular area

Tags: probability, geometry, circles

An airplane is moving (straight) within a circle of radius $R$ with constant speed $V$ for $t$ seconds. It can start at any place within the circle and move in each direction (uniform distributions).  What is the probability that it gets out of the circle (as a function of $V$, $t$ and $R$)?

Comment: Won't you please simplify this problem and eliminate irrelevancies by setting $R=1$ and $v t = r$ to clarify that this problem depends solely on a single independent variable ($r$)?  The terms $v$ and $t$ are always multiplied together, and the relevant variable is the radius distance from the airplane's starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the center of our circle $A$, the disk bounded by it $D(A, R)$ and the velocity vector by $\vec{V}$. We know $|\vec{V}| = V$. Finally, denote the event that our plane leaves the circle $L$.

The key observation is that the locus of starting points such that the plane doesn't leave $D$ is congruent for any possible direction: our problem is symmetric with respect to the direction. Therefore, $\mathbb{P}[L|\vec{V}] = \mathbb{P}[L]$, and we can consider the direction fixed.

Let's fix the direction of $\vec{V}$ and find this locus. Define $f(x) = x + t\vec{V}$ be the function that, given a takeoff point, returns the plane's landing.

Let $D_1 = \{x:f(x) \in D\}$ be the set of points, both inside and outside $O$ such, that the plane starting from there would end up inside $D$. Then $D_1$ is also a disk with radius $R$ and center $f^{-1}(A) = A - t\vec{V}$.

Of course, the starting point of the plane must be in $D$, so it must be in $D \cap D_1$.

Thus, the probability that our plane leaves $D$ equals the probability that our starting point is in $D \cap D_1$.

The probability that a uniformly random point is inside a region is proportional to the area of that region, so we need to find $\frac{\mathbb{A}(D \cap D_1)}{\mathbb{A}(D)}$ where $\mathbb{A}$ denotes area.

$\mathbb{A}(D \cap D_1)$ is twice the area of a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).

If $tV > 2R$ the disks don't intersect, and the probability to leave $D$ is 1. Let's assume $tV \leq 2R$.

Our central angle is $\theta = 2\arccos(\frac{tV}{2R})$, so $\sin(\theta) = \frac{tV}{R}\sqrt{1 - \big(\frac{tv}{2R}\big)^2}$

Since we have two segments, the total intersection area is

$$\mathbb{A}(D \cap D_1) = R^2(\theta - \sin\theta)$$

Therefore, the probability that the plane leaves the circle (denote this event $L$) is

$$\mathbb{P}[L] = 1 - \frac{\mathbb{A}(D \cap D_1)}{\pi R^2} = 1 - \frac{\theta - \sin(\theta)}{\pi} =
1 - \frac{2\arccos(\frac{tv}{2R}) - \frac{tV}{R}\sqrt{1 - \big(\frac{tV}{2R}\big)^2}}{\pi}$$

[image: map]

Comment: I do not believe this is correct because it assumes (incorrectly) that each candidate separation of circle centers is equally likely, which contradicts the explicit condition that the airplane's starting position can be anywhere in the given circle, with uniform distribution.  It is far more likely the airplane will begin closer to the perimeter of the circle than to its center, but the above calculation does not include this fact (as far as I can see).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The distance between circle centers is fixed - $tV$, the total distance traveled, and has nothing to do with place starting point. Therefore, if you start in the intersection and go $tV$ in the x direction, you stay in the circle. Otherwise, if you go $tV$ in the x direction, you end outside the circle. The probability that the plane will begin closer to the perimeter is part of the area calculation, both of the circle, and the segments.

Comment: What if you start in the intersection region (area) and then go off at an arbitrary direction?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork When building the circle, assume a fixed direction. For any fixed direction, you'll get the exact same value $P$. In the end, you can integrate over the distribution of the direction, $\mathbb{P}[\text{get out}] = \int \mathbb{P}[\text{get out} | V] p(V) dV = \int P \times p(V) dV = P \int p(V) dV = P$.

Comment: Your "explanation" is confusing, and I think you'll realize that if you plug in your formulas with $R=1$, $vt = 1/3$.  See what answer you get, and whether it even makes sense.  Even with a fixed direction (offset) your calculation does not properly calculate 1) the probability the flight will emerge from the original circle, and 2) that the original starting point is "uniformly distributed" within the original circle.  Also, please use a consistent notation.  You use different symbols for probability, "volume" or speed, etc.  Fix:  "the probability the place [sic] leaves the circle."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I did indeed have algebraic mistakes, which caused the result to not make sense. Edited the answer, also made it more formal.

Answer (score 5):

Let us simplify the problem and reduce it to its core properties.  Let the radius of the original "bounding" circle be $1$, and the (linear) flight distance be $vt =r$.  Our problem can be characterized entirely by the value of $r$.

If $r>2$, then every airplane escapes the bounding circle, no matter its takeoff point; the probability of escape is thus $P_{r>2} = 1$.

Here is a figure illustrating a more general case for a given $r<1$.  If the airplane takeoff point is inside the annulus of inner radius $1-r$, then the airplane will never escape, regardless of its flight direction.  That is shown by the white core of the disk.  The probability of the plane **not** escaping is the ratio of the inner (white) disk region divided by the area of the bounding disk, i.e.,  $P = {\pi r^2 \over \pi 1^2} = r^2$.  But of course that is not the final solution.  We must calculate the probability that if the airplane's takeoff point is in the pink annulus, that it escapes.

[image: Bounding circle and airplane region]

Now look at the more interesting case:

[image]

Here $x$ is the distance of the takeoff point from the bounding disk center (in any direction).  The airplane will land somewhere along the perimeter of the green disk.  The (one-dimensional) length of the purple arc divided by the total circumference of the green disk is the probability the airplane will land outside the bounding disk.  This, in turn, depends upon the angle $\theta$, as shown.

We use the law of cosines for the dashed triangle, which has sides of known length:

$$1^2 = x^2 + r^2 - 2 x r \cos (\theta),$$

or

$$\theta = \arccos \left( {x^2 + r^2 - 1 \over 2 x r} \right).$$

The probability the airplane lands *inside* the bounding disk is $P = \theta/\pi$, and thus the probability the airplane lands outside is $1 - \theta/\pi$.

Now we must integrate all possible values of $x$, as:

$$\int\limits_{x=1 - 2 r}^1 2 \pi x\ {1 \over \pi} \arccos \left( {x^2 + r^2 - 1 \over 2 x r} \right) \ dx$$

One then performs this integral, collects terms and simplifies.

Comment: "I honestly do not see how the other "solutions" here incorporate this fact." Any area calculation automatically incorporates this fact. In fact, this fact follows from an area calculation of infinitesimal strips.

Comment: This integral seems to integrate to an imaginary number for $r=\frac{1}{3}$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(2pi+x)(1+%2F+(pi%2F2))+acos((x%5E2+%2B+1%2F9-1)+%2F+(2%2F3+x))+from+1%2F3+to+1

Comment: "One then performs this integral"... Solving Riemann hypothesis looks like a much simpler problem :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am starting to get how this works! How do you get the probability P=θ/(π/2)? Why not θ/π?

Comment: @baskon1:  You are correct:  It should be $\theta/\pi$... so changed.  Thanks!

Comment: One last question. In the integral why do we use 2πx? Couldn't we just calculate the average θ/π using this integral?

Comment: @baskon1 You need to multiply $\theta/\pi$ by the density $f(x)$ of the distance from a random point in the circle to the center. $f(x) = 2x$ not $2\pi x$ to be a proper density, but the important part is, it is proportional to $x$. You should also pay attention to the bounds of the integral: it needs to be from $0$, not $1-2r$, but for $r < 1-r$ the $\arccos$ is undefined and $\theta = \pi$ (the integrand is nonzero then so you can't just shift the bounds). Finally, note that the integral gives the probability to stay, so you need to subtract from 1.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

assuming $r=Vt < 2R$, and once starts not changing direction.

pick a point $c$ inside the circle for the plane starting point, draw a circle or radius $r$, find the chord angle $\theta$ of the intersections.  The probability of the plane getting out of the big circle is $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$.

In case $r>2R$, there is no intersection, so probability is 1.

Comment: The tricky part is performing the integral...

Answer (score 0):

Consider a circle of radius $Vt$ with center r away from the center of the first circle, itself having radius R. The chances Escape is 1 minus the ratio of the area of overlap between the two circles to the area of the second circle.

Let the radius of the circle be R. Let initial distance from center of circle be r. Let u=V=Velocity and t=time. $\theta$ is angle of velocity vector with respect to displacement vector from center of circle.

By symmetry, the probability of escape is the same for positions the same distance from the center, so probability is a function of r, $P(r)$.

The final distance from the center is $d^2=r^2+u^2t^2-2rut\cos{\theta}$ and we have our crossing points at $d=R$.

So: $$\cos{\theta}=\frac{r^2+u^2t^2-R^2}{2rut}$$

Solve for the range of $\theta$ and divide by $2\pi$. This will give you P(r). We can approximate with a Taylor Series:

$$1-\frac{\theta^2}{2}=\frac{r^2+u^2t^2-R^2}{2rut}$$

So $\Delta \theta /2 \pi \approx \frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{R^2-(r-ut)^2}{rut}}\approx P(r)$

$r$ can take on values uniformly from $r$ to $R$ giving a probability of $\frac{2r}{R^2}$.

$$P\approx\int_0^R\frac{2r}{\pi R^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2-(r-ut)^2}{rut}}dr$$

Comment: With the Taylor approximation of cosine, how much do we lose in accuracy?